# editable div only shows first div element in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am trying to get the contents of the editable div, but it only gets the content of 1st div no matter what div I click on.

My code:

```php
//$ff is array that has sql data stored
foreach ($ff as $data) {
  //$somedata is php variable and it's data
  // keep changing as it's fetching name from database
  echo "<h4 class='editme' id='grid' contentEditable='true'>{$data['name']}</h4>";
        }
    
 echo "<script>
     $('h4.editme').click(function(){
      var content = $('#grid').html();
       console.log(content);
        });
 </script>";
```

It does print the data in console when I click on the div (and it makes the div editable) but it only shows the output as of 1st div content, no matter if I click on first div, second and so on it shows only first div output.

For example,

My data on website is

```
NameA
NameB
NameC
NameD
.....
NameH
```

After those 10 names are displayed I click on let's say NameD it makes it editable div and on console it prints `NameA` instead no matter on what div I click on.

All of these div have same `id` , `classname` etc. as I checked on html code on my website while inspecting the code. How do I make the div print the right div contents on editable?

Comment: html id's should be unique, use `$(this).html();` instead

Comment: Thanks, it's working now. @LawrenceCherone

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach ($ff as $key=>$data) { //$ff is array that has sql data stored
  echo "<h4 class='editme' id='grid{$key}' contentEditable='true'>{$data['name']}</h4>"; //$somedata is php variable and it's data keep changing as it's fetching name from database
}

echo "<script>
$('h4.editme').click(function(){
var content = $(this).html();
console.log(content);
});
</script>";
```

Comment: What exactly was wrong with OPs code, what did you change?